# Why isn't my video uploading in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms, html5-video

I'm building on top of on Refinery CMS (www.refineryCMS) and on one of my web pages I need and embedded mp4 video (I can save the video into another format if thats the issue, though I doubt it is, I've already tried both saving the video as both a .avi and a .ogg and neither of those solved the issue). Pages created using Refinery's front end are handled by the app/views/pages/show.html.erb file so I modified that file with code that looks like

```
<% if @page.title == 'CBCTIntegration' %>
.
. Some html5 code
.
<%= video_tag "CBCT_WEB.mp4", :size =>"480x270", :controls => true, :autobuffer = true      %>
.
. More html5 code
.
<% end %>
```

Since I noticed that by default there was no /public/videos folder which is where video_tag defaults to and since running rake refinery:override commands yielded no results so I used mkdir to create such a folder and moved my video in there. The controls (pause, play, viewing area, ect al.) load just fine to the correct dimensions but the video won't play.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like? Can your browser `GET` whatever video URL is generated? Do you have any error messages in your server logs?

Comment: <video autobuffer="autobuffer" controls="controls" height="270" src="/videos/CBCT_WEB.mp4?1326490385" width="480">...</video>

Comment: Thats what the generated html looks like, I'll look at the messages in my server logs to see if there's any related errors.

Comment: I've confirmed that there's no errors in either the server or the development logs related to the issue I'm having.

Comment: Does it work in other browsers? Could it be a browser / MIME type issue.

Comment: Its not that. I tested it with the latest versions of Chrome, Fire Fox and Internet Explorer. Doesn't work on any of them.

Comment: If you use `wget` or `curl` to download `http://server/videos/CBCT_WEB.mp4?1326490385` does the download happen as expected?